# Calling a method in a managed bean from URL Request

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, managed-bean

I'm working on Spring MVC with richfaces. 
Is there a way to call a method in a managed bean Controller from URL?

e.g: website.com/somecontroller/somemethod?x=1

I tried @RequestMapping but didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser client want to access to an URL, the managed beans declared in the page will be created, the constructor and `@PostConstruct` methods will be invoked server side.

You can recover the parameters using `@ManagedProperty` as proposed by BalusC (as he says, the JSF-ish way):

- [Parameters in URL JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3355611/1065197)

If that answer doesn't fit for your needs, you can recover the request object and get the parameters one by one, as stated in the question:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.
    getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
String clipId = request.getParameter("x");
```