# Get JSF full url

Tags: url, jsf-2

Sorry if it was asked before, I couldn't found.

I have the following link:

http://www.mysite.kg/news/news.xhtml?id=2

How can I get value after question mark e.g id=2 from URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How get GET parameters with JSF2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775179/how-get-get-parameters-with-jsf2)

Comment: here your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355611/parameter-in-url-jsf2

Comment: I have tried them, both of them not working as I am always getting 0

Answer (score 0):

I guess that solves:

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        String id = "";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "id=(\\d+)" );
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( url );
        if ( matcher.find() )
            id = matcher.group( 1 );
```